# SQL Server full text search - only works with full string?

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

I've setup a full text index on a table, there's a column containing the type (always .txt) and a text column with is just a long string in binary. The only way I can get a result with the below query is if the string matches the whole contents of the indexed field.

```
SELECT [Pages].[Id] 
FROM [Pages]
WHERE CONTAINS([Text], '"this is a test"')
```

The above returns the one record that has the binary for "this is a test".

```
SELECT [Pages].[Id] 
FROM [Pages]
WHERE CONTAINS([Text], '"test"')
```

The above returns nothing, even though I would expect it to return the record is my previous example.

Any ideas on why this could be happening?

Comment: isn't it looking for `"test"` and you only have `test"`?

Comment: try checking for test or test" or *test"

Comment: @Azar 'test' working, but why doesn't 'this'?

Comment: Because you are trying to check for "test" where as the original text contains just "**** a test" i,e " is missing infront of test.

Comment: @Azar But if I put "test I get an error.

Comment: what is the error ?

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below

```
SELECT [Pages].[Id] 
FROM [Pages]
WHERE CONTAINS([Text], '*test*')
```

If you are still having issues with the query then please update the stats of full text index and check.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/populate-full-text-indexes